# groupby pandas dataframe and create another dataframe which represents the groupby results horizontally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe by the name usabledata with columns ['marker','action','id']

```
usabledata = pd.DataFrame(columns=['marker','action','id'])
```

I ran the following commands on the usabledata dataframe:

```
counts = usabledata.groupby(['marker','action']).count()
counts = counts.drop(['marker','action'])
print counts

                        id 
marker  action   
1       A               377 
        B               224
        C               9881 
        D               149946 
2       A               481 
        B               397
        C               7468 
        D               147581 
3       A               538 
        B               458
        D               145916
```

Now, I want to create a pandas dataframe with the following format:

```
Marker      A      B     C     D
1           377    224   9881   149946
2           481    397   7468   147581
3           538    458   0      145916
```

Is it possible to do this using pandas dataframe in ipython notebook?

Also, is it possible to delete a column for example the column 'C' after obtaining this desired output?

Another doubt in the same problem, after obtaining the desired output how can I add another column 'Fraction' which is just a ratio of the columns 'A' and 'D'?

Comment: @EdChum can you help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC then you can call [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
In [124]:
gp.unstack().fillna(0)

Out[124]:
       action                   
marker      A    B     C       D
id                              
1         377  224  9881  149946
2         481  397  7468  147581
3         538  458     0  145916
```

Comment: Thanks @EdChum can you please check the edit and let me know if that is possible too?

Comment: You can either call `drop(columns=['C'])` or just filter it out `gp.unstack().fillna(0).ix[:,['A','B','D']`

Comment: I did this to make the delete work. unstacked = gp.unstack().fillna(0) unstacked.drop(unstacked[['C']])